# Exporting reports at scheduled times using .Net Application

Tags: .net, wpf, reporting-services, ssis

I have a requirement of running and exporting daily reports which has the same key column. 
Let's say we have around 50 reports for a day and it runs at its execution time(time varies for each report) and the report has to be exported as excel file.

Another app that shows the status of the reports and if the user wants to review the report, the excel file has to be opened on a button click/hyperlink click.
what would be the best way to accomplish this task.My current approach is as below

I have created stored procs for all of reports that inserts the data to a master table with Datestamp. From the master table, a maxtrix report pulls report data using reportid and the same report is used for exporting the reports as excel file.
Stored procs are scheduled as SQL jobs at the exection time of the reports. when the proc run, it will insert reportid to a table which is used in datadriven subscriptions(exports to excel files).

Data driven subscriptions run every 5 minutes  to generate the reports. If a report runs at 10.02 am and the subscription starts at 10.05 am, few reports have the time delay of 5 minutes between when the report proc was executed and when the report was exported.
I am looking for the ways to export the report, after the data is inserted to master table.

I had locking issues when I tried to call the ADDEVENT with susbcriptionid as few reports run at the same time.

Please let me if you have any methods that will work for this scenario.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

what about:  presenting the reports in browser with SSRS and alow the users to export the report; if the user needs to change the report he can export it to excel and update it, of course this will not update the data on the database server;
 or you could use a custom application to update the data, put a link to the application in the SSRS report, or use an action on a design element;

Comment: We are exporting the reports as excel files, so it will reduce end users time in exporting the report manually. Report  size varies from 4 KB to 3 MB. Also I am using a matrix report which pulls different reports using report id. If the end user exports the report, it will have a default name while exporting and the user has to manually type the name of the report. To avoid those issues, I am looking for ways to export them automatically. For exporting I have a SSIS Package created with the help of SSRS webservice. Can multiple instances of same package run at the same time withdifferentinput

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use SSIS Packages , you should be able to run the procedures in the SSIS package using a OLE DB Command  task;
 then when the task of running the stored procedures is completed the flow to continue with the tasks that generate the reports/report.

Also I would use the SSIS System variable StartTime as a timestamp, it is the time when the package started  to run;

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your reply. Sorry,I was off to work for few days, so i couldn't reply earlier. I have another question . is it possible that I can run multiple instances  of SSIS package with different parameters. I am still working on calling the ssis package on  execution time of the reports.Would I get any deadlocks if I call a SSIS package with different parameters at the same time?

Comment: It is possible to run the same package with two, or more, configuration files. You put the parameters in the config files, so the answer is yes you can run multiple instances of SSIS package with different parameters. About deadlocks if you proceed so, that depends on what exactly the package does and what data it access, there is no direct answer to this, but you if you see performance issues then maybe you could run the SSIS package at different times.